# Jenkinsfile XmlParser().parseText(xml_file) does not work with XML node names

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, traversal

it is needed to extract some value from some XML file. Extraction is triggered from a Jenkinsfile. The following code works fine in my Jenkinsfile:

```
    def xml_file_contents = new XmlParser().parseText(xml_file)
    def value_i_need_to_extract = xml_file_contents.children()[4].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0].text().toString()
```

However, the XML file that is parsed, might get modified later, therefore traversing by XML node names and not with children() method would be a muh better idea. However, every time I apply something like this:

```
    def value_i_need_to_extract = xml_file_contents.nodename.nodename.nodename.nodename.text().toString()
```

I receive the following error:

```
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node remote
```

I have tried traversing by node names with different XML files and different node names, but the result is always an error.

And this error appears despite the fact that I have approved all security features required by Jenkins In-process Script Approval.

Problem-illustrating examples:

Code A:

```
def remote_repo = xml_file_contents.children()[3].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0]
echo 'Remote repository is:' + remote_repo.toString()
```

Output A:

```
Remote repository is:remote[attributes={}; value=[http://LAPTOP/svn/localrepo/app/component/RC]]
```

Code B:

```
def remote_repo = xml_file_contents.children()[3].children()[0].children()[0].children()[0].text()
echo 'Remote repository is:' + remote_repo.toString()
```

Output B:

```
Remote repository is:http://LAPTOP/svn/localrepo/app/component/RC
```

Code C:

```
def remote_repo = xml_file_contents.children()[3].children()[0].children()[0].remote.text()
```

Output C:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node remote
```

Do you know what might be the reason for such behavior? Is there a way to traverse XML by node names?

Sample XML file:

```
    <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <project>
      <description>Just a sample build job</description>
      <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
      <properties>
        <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty plugin="jira@3.0.11"/>
      </properties>
      <scm class="hudson.scm.SubversionSCM" plugin="subversion@2.12.2">
        <locations>
          <hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
            <remote>http://LAPTOP/svn/localrepo/subfolder/componentname/RC</remote>
            <credentialsId>justsomeid</credentialsId>
            <local>.</local>
            <depthOption>infinity</depthOption>
            <ignoreExternalsOption>true</ignoreExternalsOption>
            <cancelProcessOnExternalsFail>true</cancelProcessOnExternalsFail>
          </hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
        </locations>
        <excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
        <includedRegions></includedRegions>
        <excludedUsers></excludedUsers>
        <excludedRevprop></excludedRevprop>
        <excludedCommitMessages></excludedCommitMessages>
        <workspaceUpdater class="hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater"/>
        <ignoreDirPropChanges>false</ignoreDirPropChanges>
        <filterChangelog>false</filterChangelog>
        <quietOperation>true</quietOperation>
      </scm>
      <canRoam>true</canRoam>
      <disabled>false</disabled>
      <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
      <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
      <triggers/>
      <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
      <builders/>
      <publishers>
        <hudson.plugins.ws__cleanup.WsCleanup plugin="ws-cleanup@0.37">
          <patterns class="empty-list"/>
          <deleteDirs>false</deleteDirs>
          <skipWhenFailed>false</skipWhenFailed>
          <cleanWhenSuccess>true</cleanWhenSuccess>
          <cleanWhenUnstable>true</cleanWhenUnstable>
          <cleanWhenFailure>true</cleanWhenFailure>
          <cleanWhenNotBuilt>true</cleanWhenNotBuilt>
          <cleanWhenAborted>true</cleanWhenAborted>
          <notFailBuild>false</notFailBuild>
          <cleanupMatrixParent>false</cleanupMatrixParent>
          <externalDelete></externalDelete>
          <disableDeferredWipeout>false</disableDeferredWipeout>
        </hudson.plugins.ws__cleanup.WsCleanup>
      </publishers>
      <buildWrappers/>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

[XmlParser should not be used](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33024) as it doesn't serialize (it only works within the master node, which should not have any executors).

Unfortunately, Jenkins doesn't offer a serializable step like it does with JSON and YAML (see [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)).

If you can turn your XML into JSON or YAML you will be able to use the `readJSON`/`readYaml` steps appropriately, and you'll also have an easier time navigating them.
If that's not possible, you should consider writing a small utility to aid you with handling XML files: that way you'll be able to run your pipeline script on agents which aren't the master node.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my Groovy console:

```
def xml_file = """<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <project>
      <description>Just a sample build job</description>
      <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
      <properties>
        <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty plugin="jira@3.0.11"/>
      </properties>
      <scm class="hudson.scm.SubversionSCM" plugin="subversion@2.12.2">
        <locations>
          <hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
            <remote>http://LAPTOP/svn/localrepo/subfolder/componentname/RC</remote>
            <credentialsId>justsomeid</credentialsId>
            <local>.</local>
            <depthOption>infinity</depthOption>
            <ignoreExternalsOption>true</ignoreExternalsOption>
            <cancelProcessOnExternalsFail>true</cancelProcessOnExternalsFail>
          </hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
        </locations>
        <excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
        <includedRegions></includedRegions>
        <excludedUsers></excludedUsers>
        <excludedRevprop></excludedRevprop>
        <excludedCommitMessages></excludedCommitMessages>
        <workspaceUpdater class="hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater"/>
        <ignoreDirPropChanges>false</ignoreDirPropChanges>
        <filterChangelog>false</filterChangelog>
        <quietOperation>true</quietOperation>
      </scm>
      <canRoam>true</canRoam>
      <disabled>false</disabled>
      <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
      <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
      <triggers/>
      <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
      <builders/>
      <publishers>
        <hudson.plugins.ws__cleanup.WsCleanup plugin="ws-cleanup@0.37">
          <patterns class="empty-list"/>
          <deleteDirs>false</deleteDirs>
          <skipWhenFailed>false</skipWhenFailed>
          <cleanWhenSuccess>true</cleanWhenSuccess>
          <cleanWhenUnstable>true</cleanWhenUnstable>
          <cleanWhenFailure>true</cleanWhenFailure>
          <cleanWhenNotBuilt>true</cleanWhenNotBuilt>
          <cleanWhenAborted>true</cleanWhenAborted>
          <notFailBuild>false</notFailBuild>
          <cleanupMatrixParent>false</cleanupMatrixParent>
          <externalDelete></externalDelete>
          <disableDeferredWipeout>false</disableDeferredWipeout>
        </hudson.plugins.ws__cleanup.WsCleanup>
      </publishers>
      <buildWrappers/>
    </project>"""

def xml_file_contents = new XmlParser().parseText(xml_file)
println xml_file_contents.scm.locations[0].children()[0].remote.text()
```

Output:

```
http://LAPTOP/svn/localrepo/subfolder/componentname/RC
```